# Iphone "shortcuts" for wifi / 3g / localization

Tags: iphone, ios

the iPhone may be a real battery hog and sometimes having the battery last till evening is hard. The obvious tips are turning localization, bluetooth, wifi, 3g and so on off. The problem is that this requires *a lot* of tipping. For example, if I just want to turn 3g off because i'm not browsing or something, I have to tap Activate -> Unlock -> Setting -> General -> Network -> 3g.

One really cool feature of Android is that you can simply swipe down (the gesture that in the new iOS 5 shows the center message) and you have all the icons for turning features on / off. Moreover, every mobile phone has different "modes" that you can activate with a few clicks and that encapsulate a set of settings. On the iPhone you just have sound on / off and the radical "aeroplane" mode.

Is there a way (shortcut, setting, app...) to set up different modes? For example, most of the times I just need to use the iPhone for messages and calls and receive pushes (mails) but not using 3g, but I want to reactivate all the features if I need to look up something on the internet or check something nearby with an app and I don't want to do dozens of clicks just to reactivate the localization, searching for networks and re-enable 3g. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Apple has added some URL shortcuts for these functions and [Jeff Broderick](https://twitter.com/#!/brdrck) (blog at http://brdrck.me/ ) has assembled a nice dashboard of these shortcuts with gorgeous icons to save the web clips to the home screen of your iOS device.

- [Wifi toggle](http://brdrck.me/settings/wifi.Default.mobileconfig) from http://brdrck.me/settings/wifi

Simply browse your iOS device to http://brdrck.me/settings/ and pick from the many web clips that he has assembled. These are basically the same as taking a web site in the iPhone configuration utility and adding it to your home screen with a nice icon. I don't see one set up for Localization/International or 3G but will poke around to see if I can figure out the syntax to get those sorted for you.

Comment: this is godly. :O

Comment: Sadly it might get pulled if it was a half baked idea or will be rolled out as a different implementation. See this [report that is't pulled from a beta version](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/11/11/30/settings_shortcuts_disabled_by_apple_in_ios_5_1_beta.html) Clearly there's desire and need for this sort of efficiency - just that it might take more time to "get right".

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this question while looking for the same answer. Unfortunately there is no way to do this unless you jailbreak your device.

Once jailbroken, a large set of toggles in notification center and also three profiles are provided by the free application called "batterydoctorpro" made by the Chinese guys who made "Battery Doctor (Battery Saver,Battery Life)" in app store (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/battery-doctor-battery-saver/id446751279?mt=8)

It is amazing to compare the programs side by side to see just how many features is Apple restricting users from having.

"Made in China" in this case is a high quality code stamp.

To not be accused of publicity, there are also others worth mentioning: ncsettings, sbsettings (and maybe others if you search for "notification center toggles"); I've went through testing of some of them but b-d-p is my subjective personal recommendation because of really good impression.

Answer (score 0):

The short cut for stopping 3G is easy. Tell Siri "Close cellular data please".

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this on any version of iOS as of iOS 5. You can however jailbreak and achieve this functionality through various applications from cydia such as "SBSettings" etc...